# Firebase cloud functions suddenly returns @grpc module error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm finding Firebase Cloud Functions to be quite unreliable.

**What happened**:

I had one function working as expected (**function A**), already deployed and okay. 
As I was building another one (**function B**), unrelated to A, cloud functions logs started reporting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@grpc/grpc-js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:37:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Maybe I messed something up. So I removed function B and deployed again. The errors still kept appearing, and function A was no longer working.

**How I tried to solve:**

- Removed the node_modules folder and ran `npm install` again.
- Installed, again, the grpc module with `npm install --save grpc`.

Nothing has solved the problem.
Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? And also on how to avoid this from happening again?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of *all* the modules you use directly in your package.json?

Comment: Yes. What's strange is that it was working and, after one deploy, it started logging this error. Packages didn't change in between deploys, and I didn't install any new module that could interfere. 
Here is my package.json:
"axios": "^0.18.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
    "grpc": "^1.21.1"

Comment: have u tried `npm install --unsafe-perm` ?? i had this similar problem but trying to connect from aws lambdas, never into gcp

Comment: Have you tried "npm install @grpc/grpc-js"? "grpc" and "@grpc/grpc-js" are different. I guess it's a similar issue. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/338

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure the reason for this behavior.

However, by following Paul Kinlan's [suggestion](https://paul.kinlan.me/google-cloud-node-npm-grpc/), the error went away (no changes in the functions whatsoever).

```
npm install
npm rebuild --build-from-source google-cloud
```

I also performed a `npm update` to make sure I had all the latest packages, following Doug's comment in my question.

If anyone figures out the cause of this error, please drop a note so we can avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the cloud function from the console and then upload it again.